# Copying or rsyncing only files from subdirectories

Tags: command-line, rsync, cp

I have a folder which is named Music. This folder contains the three subfolders Jazz, Rock and Folk. Now each of these three subfolders contains various .mp3 files. Now I want to copy the .mp3 files from all three subfolders into one folder with one command run.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-r` flag from rsync:

```
rsync -r /path/to/Music/*/*.mp3 /path/to/destination
```

This matches every `mp3` file in any subdirectory of `Music`, if you want it to just match a list of subdirectories, use `bash` Brace Expansion:

rsync -r /path/to/Music/{Jazz,Rock,Folk}/*.mp3 /path/to/destination

You could even use `--exclude` option to exclude sub-directories and directories structures.

```
rsync -rv --exclude='*/' /path/in/source/dir*/ /path/to/destination/
```

Or with sub-directories:

```
rsync -rv --exclude='*/*' /path/in/source/dir*/ /path/to/destination/
```

You could also use `scp` command as well

```
scp -r /path/to/Music/*/*.mp3 /path/to/destination
```

This was already answered in a different question here: [copying files from many directories to one using rsync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385013/copying-files-from-many-directories-to-one-using-rsync)

Comment: Just tried your first solution (right now) and that does not work. The point is that I do not want to run a rsync for each and every subdirectory but only one rsync for the directory that contains the subdirectories.

Comment: Maybe I should be more clear:

Comment: So let’s say I have a folder which is named Music. This folder contains the three subfolders Jazz, Rock and Folk. Now each of these three subfolders contains various .mp3 files. Now I want to copy the .mp3 files from all three subfolders into one folder with one command run. I tried your solutions but they copy only a single .mp3 file that is in Music folder and none of the files that are in the three subfolders.

Comment: @dessert Sorry my 2nd comment overlaped with your comment. Edited my question.

Comment: @Guebert How about that? `rsync -r Music/*/*.mp3 /path/to/other/dir`

Comment: @Tomáš Tomovčík Thanks Tomáš - Solved. It was my error. I misinterpreted the way you stated the path. I think (but maybe I am wrong) it would be more clear if you write ...source/dir/*/*.ext instead of ...source/dir*/*.ext. Anyway thanks again, works perfect now.

Comment: @dessert: Exactly I guess this is what Tomáš meant but I misinterpreted his notation of the path. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: @Guebert I guess so as well, so I just edited the answer. If this is what solved your problem please consider to accept it by clicking the checkmark on its left.